# ajax call with jquery to c# method and return error 500

Tags: c#

I have an issue. I am using this code to call the C# function:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL + "api/download",
        data: daata,
        method: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        traditional: true,
        ContentType: "application/Json;Charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "Json",
        success: function (data) {
            //Convert the Byte Data to BLOB object.
            var filename = $("title").text().replace(/['"]+/g, '')
            var blob = new Blob([data], {
                type: "application/json"
            });

            saveAs(blob, filename);
        }
    });
```

and in the C# controller, I have

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[Route("api/download")]
public  ActionResult GetApiContract(int id)
{
      //return the json 
}
```

In my local machine and in the test server it is working but in the production, I got a 500 error
I put a simple return with "some text" and looks like the ajax not call the C#

Comment: `Route("api/contract")` but you have `url: BASE_URL + "api/download`

Comment: you are right, was my mistake when typing in my code both have the same route

Comment: Alright. Next problem is that GET methods don't have bodies, so how does `int id` get set?

Comment: so for sending, the parameter "id"  will be added at the same URL? like this: BASE_URL + "api/download?id=" + $("#parameter_id").val()

Comment: Not automatically. Try `url: BASE_URL + "api/download/" + id`?

Answer (score 0):

fix the route

```
[Route("~/api/download/{id}")]
public  ActionResult GetApiContract(int id)
{
      //return the json 
}
```

and ajax

```
var id= ... your code

$.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL + "/api/download/"+id,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            //Convert the Byte Data to BLOB object.
            var filename = $("title").text().replace(/['"]+/g, '')
            var blob = new Blob([data], {
                type: "application/json"
            });

            saveAs(blob, filename);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

i found the issue, I do not why but when I change the Route
`[Route("~/api/download")] to [Route("download")]` then the issue is solved